# How to remove a bogus email from Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I accidentally sent an email to a work colleague using a malformed email address and it bounced back. Unfortunately, even after sending email to the correct address, that old bogus one is still in the list (first) when I type his first name into the "To" field of an email.

I found this: http://www.ehow.com/how_6804366_remove-outlook-contacts.html

...but his valid email address is the *only* entry I have in my Contacts, so that method doens't help.

Where is the bogus email address stored, and how can I expunge it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a new email and enter the start of the address so that the bad address appears in the drop down list.  Then cursor down to that bad address and press Delete when it is highlighted.  That's all there is to it!